# How you stop 'wget' after it gets a 404?

Tags: bash, shell-script, wget

If you use brace expansion with `wget`, you can fetch sequentially-numbered images with ease:

```
$ wget 'http://www.iqandreas.com/sample-images/100-100-color/'{90..110}'.jpg'
```

It fetches the first 10 files numbered `90.jpg` to `99.jpg` just fine, but `100.jpg` and onward return a *404: File not found* error (I only have 100 images stored on the server). These non-existent files become more of "a problem" if you use a larger range, such as `{00..200}`, with 100 non-existent files, it increases the script's execution time, and might even become a slight burden (or at least annoyance) on the server.

Is there any way for `wget` to stop after it has received its first 404 error? (or even better, two in a row, in case there was a missing file in the range for another reason) The answer does not need to use brace expansion; loops are fine too.

Comment: In a real-time scenario, you may want to hit every URL to know the status. `1, 2 or even n failures` is not the right way when you know `[begin .. end]` indices. Why would you specify `[1..200]` range when you know there are only 100 images in `[1..100]`. I guess you can try GNU `parallel` for simultaneous requests to speed up the process.

Comment: @SparKotॐ The key is I _don't_ know there are only 100 images on the server, I want the script to download as many images as it can in the series until it has figured out where the end is.

Answer (score 12):

If you're happy with a loop:

```
for url in 'http://www.iqandreas.com/sample-images/100-100-color/'{90..110}'.jpg'
do
    wget "$url" || break
done
```

That will run `wget` for each URL in your expansion until it fails, and then `break` out of the loop.

If you want two failures in a row it gets a bit more complicated:

```
for url in 'http://www.iqandreas.com/sample-images/100-100-color/'{90..110}'.jpg'
do
    if wget "$url"
    then
        failed=
    elif [ "$failed" ]
    then
        break
    else
        failed=yes
    fi
done
```

You can shrink that a little with `&&` and `||` instead of `if`, but it gets pretty ugly.

I don't believe `wget` has anything built in to do that.

Comment: May I suggest using `elif` to make the second example clearer? Something like this perhaps? https://gist.github.com/IQAndreas/84cae3f0193b67691ff2 (it only adds one extra line, not including putting the `then`s on the same line as the `if`s)

Comment: Fair enough. The one-line translation isn't as straightforward now, but it isn't much good anyway.

Answer (score 10):

You could use the `$?` variable to get the return code of wget. If it's non-zero then it means an error occured and you tally it up until it reached a threshold, then it could break out of the loop.

Something like this off the top of my head

```
#!/bin/bash

threshold=0
for x in {90..110}; do
    wget 'http://www.iqandreas.com/sample-images/100-100-color/'$x'.jpg'
    wgetreturn=$?
    if [[ $wgetreturn -ne 0 ]]; then
        threshold=$(($threshold+$wgetreturn))
        if [[ $threshold -eq 16 ]]; then
                break
        fi
    fi
done
```

The for loop can be cleaned up a bit, but you can understand the general idea.

Changing the `$threshold -eq 16` to `-eq 24` would mean it would fail 3 times before it would stop, however it wouldn't be twice in a row, it would be if it failed twice in the loop.

The reason why `16` and `24` are used is that is the total of the return codes.
wget responds with a return code of `8` when it receives a response code that corresponds to an error from the server, and thus `16` is the total after 2 errors.

Stopping when failures only occur twice in a row can be done by resetting the threshold whenever `wget` succeeds, i.e. when the return code is 0

---

A list of wget return codes can be found here - http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html

Comment: Although it can be deduced from the answer, you might want to explicitly point out that a 404 error returns an exit code of `8`, hence the [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) of `16` and `24`.

Comment: I've updated my answer

Answer (score 4):

IMO, focusing in on `wget`'s exit code/status may be too naive for some use-cases, so here is one that considers the HTTP Status Code as well for some granular decision making.

`wget` provides a `-S/--server-response` flag to print out the HTTP Response Headers on `STDERR` of the command - which we can extract and act upon.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eu

error_max=2
error_count=0

urls=( 'http://www.iqandreas.com/sample-images/100-100-color/'{90..110}'.jpg' )

for url in "${urls[@]}"; do
  set +e
  http_status=$( wget --server-response -c "$url" 2>&1 )
  exit_status=$?
  http_status=$( awk '/HTTP\//{ print $2 }' <<<"$http_status" | tail -n 1 )

  if (( http_status >= 400 )); then
    # Considering only HTTP Status errors
    case "$http_status" in
      # Define your actions for each 4XX Status Code below
      410) : Gone
        ;;
      416) : Requested Range Not Satisfiable
        error_count=0  # Reset error_count in case of `wget -c`
        ;;
      403) : Forbidden
        ;&
      404) : Not Found
        ;&
      *)     (( error_count++ ))
        ;;
    esac
  elif (( http_status >= 300 )); then
     # We're unlikely to reach here in case of 1XX, 3XX in $http_status
     # but ..
     exit_status=0
  elif (( http_status >= 200 )); then
     # 2XX in $http_status considered successful
     exit_status=0
  elif (( exit_status > 0 )); then

    # Where wget's exit status is one of
    # 1   Generic error code.
    # 2   Parse error 
    #     - when parsing command-line options, the .wgetrc or .netrc...
    # 3   File I/O error.
    # 4   Network failure.
    # 5   SSL verification failure.
    # 6   Username/password authentication failure.
    # 7   Protocol errors.

    (( error_count++ ))
  fi

  echo "$url -> http_status: $http_status, exit_status=$exit_status, error_count=$error_count" >&2

  if (( error_count >= error_max )); then
    echo "error_count $error_count >= $error_max, bailing out .." >&2
    exit "$exit_status"
  fi

done
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU Parallel this ought to work:

```
parallel --halt 1 wget ::: 'http://www.iqandreas.com/sample-images/100-100-color/'{90..110}'.jpg'
```

From version 20140722 you can almost have your "two in a row"-failure: --halt 2% will allow for 2% of the jobs to fail:

```
parallel --halt 2% wget ::: 'http://www.iqandreas.com/sample-images/100-100-color/'{90..110}'.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0):

What I've used successfully is

```
wget 'http://www.iqandreas.com/sample-images/100-100-color/'{90..110}'.jpg' 2>&1 | grep -q 'ERROR 404: Not Found'
```

`grep -q` looks for the 404 error message pattern in its input and dies as soon as it sees it.  `wget` receives a SIGPIPE signal as soon as it tries to write to the pipe from which `grep` is no longer reading.  In practice `wget` dies pretty quickly after getting that first 404.

Answer (score -1):

In python you can do

```
from subprocess import *

def main():
    for i in range(90, 110):
       try :
          url = "url/"+str(i)
          check_output(["wget", url])
       except CalledProcessError:
          print "Wget returned none zero output, quiting"
          sys.exit(0)
```

Checkout the documentation for subprocess if you want to do more https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Unless `check_output` does some magic around `wget` to detect a `404` - I don't believe there are adequate checks here and so doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: It does, read the docs. It checks the output in stdout or stderr. wget has a specific code for 404's